# Does the definition of positive or null recurrence require aperiodicity?

Tags: markov-chains

Do the notions of null or positive recurrence have to be defined with respect to irreducible, aperiodic chains or does irreducibility suffice?

Comment: Sorry but after your rapid succession of basic questions on the subject, one needs to know: are you following a textbook? If not, why?

Comment: @Did I am following a textbook and that is where this question came from. In Lawler's Stochastic Processes, Chapter 2 defines null and positive recurrence only for irreducible, aperiodic chains, which is why I wonder whether periodicity is needed here?

Comment: @Did Ditto for the other two questions I posed; I was not able to find an answer to either on the book. If you could point me to a resource or post an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: The trouble is that you seem to stumble on **very basic** obstacles, well below the subject you are trying to tackle... hence my advice for a reference would be a mildly general and mildly complete textbook on probability theory (say, Durrett), **to be worked on thoroughly** before continuing the present string of essentially irrelevant questions.